# pretty printing Z3 with C APIs

Tags: c++, c, z3

Is there a way to print an AST in human readable form, as in the Python APIs?
I would like to have something like

```
(x = 3) ^ (f(3) > 2)
```

Instead of

```
(and (= x 3) (> (f 3) 2)
```

Comment: Actually, the prefix form is more of a "traditional" AST representation: it implies operator precedence, associativity, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Z3 C/C++ API does not have this feature. The pretty printer in the Z3 Python API was implemented in Python. It is not part of the core API. The Z3 Python printer is implemented in the file `src/api/python/z3printer.py` (see [here](https://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8f7494cb0456ff85003cc83f7f08cdedba5d1b27#src/api/python/z3printer.py)). It is possible to re-implement it in C/C++ using C/C++ like notation.